# Weird behavior with variables in Release vs. Debug builds

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm simply trying to compare two strings to one another but I'm seeing wildly different behavior in my Release build. The Debug build works as expected. I haven't made any changes to optimizations other than the default values that Visual Studio 2010 sets.

Here's my code:

```
wchar_t validCRC[] = L"0xd07153b9";
wchar_t thisCRC[] = L"0xd07153b9"; // this is calculated on the fly but I get same behavior if I set it manually. i also tried setting these both to L"hello" and got same result

int cmp = 0;
cmp = wcscmp(validCRC, thisCRC); // if I put a breakpoint here, the visual studio debugger says 'cmp' is not in scope. 
pLog->Write("value of cmp: %d", cmp); // in both DEBUG and RELEASE, this prints "value of cmp: 0"

if (cmp == 0)
{ // yet for some reason, the DEBUG build follows this path
    return true;
}
else
{ // the RELEASE build follows this path
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of cmp if not 0?

Comment: That's not the real code, is it? Post something minimal that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the calculated thisCRC is not null-terminated ?

Comment: @ Dabbler - i confirmed the value of cmp is 0 in both builds.
@ K-ballo - I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. Do you want a void main() around it?
@ ThierryFranzetti - but they're both being set the same way using L"stringhere"

Comment: How do you determine that false is being returned? I assume the whole code is in a function, and the caller checks the return value. Can you show us how you do that?

Comment: @Dabbler - arg things seem to be working now that I'm looking at what's actually returned by the function. Before I was setting breakpoints and the wrong breakpoint was being trigger. That's really the actual (but far less serious) problem.

Comment: Then the problem is due to optimization performed by the compiler. In a release build (i.e. with optimization), the debugger often displays values of variables incorrectly and, when stepping, the point of execution can seem to be where it really isn't. This is because the correlation between source code lines and generated machine code is much less direct than in non-optimized code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Release builds are optimized, so it's often hard for the debugger to give you values of individual variables, especially local variables which are often stored registers that are used for something else a few instructions later.

That's why you use a *debug* build for *debugging*, and the *release* build for the build that you will *release*.

If you really need to debug a problem that only occurs in a release build (uninitialized variables are very commonly the reason there), you could use a compiler-specific #pragma to only de-optimize certain parts, or you could de-optimize certain files, or you could make use of printf instructions.

EDIT: When you say "follow" this path, you probably mean that's what it looks like when you step through it in the debugger. Again, the code is optimized, so the assembly doesn't match the source code. Returns in particular are often optimized so that there is only one actual return instruction in the assembly. So stepping through the code in a release build is not a reliable way to determine what's going on.

Once again, the proper way to debug release builds is using printfs and other mechanisms. You can still use the debugger to get a general sense of what's going on, but you can't rely on details like this.

Comment: Using printf confirms that cmp is 0 in both builds

Comment: Exactly! printf doesn't lie. Variable values, however, do (in release builds). In some environments in some debuggers, you may see flat out incorrect values. So again, if you want to debug something in the debugger, use the debug build. For release builds, you'll need other means of debugging, like printf.

Comment: Okay, I saw your edit, so I edited my answer. Again: Debugger in release builds is bound to give you misleading information. The result is what counts.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the value instead of relying on the debugger in the Release mode. The optimizer is very agressive and your symbols may point to code that is being optimized away.

Comment: I did and in both cases the value of cmp is 0